# Chrome Policy List on Fedora

Tags: google-chrome, fedora

I've installed Chrome Version 74.0.3729.131 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Fedora 30 from the official google-chrome repository, and if I go to the chrome://settings/help I see the little "Your browser is managed by your organization" thing on my home computer (so no organization).

So, I go to chrome://policy and see two entries for the policies:

AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist
*.fedoraproject.org

AuthServerWhitelist*.fedoraproject.org

How can I disable this "Your browser is managed by your organization" stuff and remove these whitelists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I just noticed this too (and I'm pretty miffed)!

Delete

```
    /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/00_gssapi.json
```

Comment: Deleting didn't work for me, but replacing the contents with {} worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

You can remove it by the line:

```
sudo dnf remove fedora-chromium-config
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Also to prevent it from being installed in the future you can exclude it from dnf by adding the following line to /etc/dnf/dnf.conf:

excludepkgs=fedora-chromium-config*

Answer (score 0):

How did this get here?  This is my personal computer.. (Fedora 33).  Is it there for a reason?  disabling authentication sounds like a good idea if that authentication is corrupted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).